# Can a geometric series be Cauchy?

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, visualization, geometric-series

[image]

Each of the purple squares has 1/4 of the area of the next larger square (1/2×1/2 = 1/4, 1/4×1/4 = 1/16, etc.). The sum of the areas of the purple squares is one third of the area of the large square.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#/media/File:GeometricSquares.svg

I'm wondering whether the geometric series shown is Cauchy. It eventually reaches a limit that is on the upper right hand corner. Converges to the black dot on the upper right hand corner.

---

Similarly,
if the sequence shown below continues and approaches the origin, the center of the picture, I think the picture below is "pell series"?, does the "pell series" converge because it is Cauchy and reaches the center of the graph eventuall?

[image]

Comment: Yes, because it's converges.If $-1<q<1$ then the sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Any convergent series is Cauchy ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

For $n,p>0$,  Let $$S_n=1/4+1/4^2+...1/4^n . $$

$$S_{n+p}-S_n=$$
$$1/4^{n+1}\Bigl(1+1/4+...1/4^{p-1}\Bigr) $$

$$=1/4^{n+1}\frac {1-1/4^p}{1-1/4} $$

$$\le \frac {1}{3.4^n}. $$

thus

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists N\in\mathbb N \;\;: \forall n>N   \;\;\forall p>0$$
$$|S_{n+p}-S_n|\le \frac {1}{3.4^n}<\epsilon $$

because $\lim_{+\infty}\frac {1}{3.4^n}=0$.
$(S_n)$ is Cauchy...

Comment: Where does the $3.4^n$ in the denominator come from? Or is that meant to be $(3/4)^n$?